# How do I check sendmail's mode of operation?

Tags: wrapper, sendmail

I have created a wrapper around the `sendmail` executable, and it should not actually do anything unless `sendmail` is being invoked in [its default mode of operation](https://lists.debian.org/lsb-spec/1999/11/msg00043.html).

How to reliably determine whether this is the case?
What I have thus far:

- the executable's name must be `sendmail`
- none of the words on command arguments must be `-I` or start with `-b` except `-bm`

Will that be perfect - regardless of which implementation of `sendmail` is actually being used - or may it misclassify certain cases?

Answer (score 0):

You should approach it from the other side. Check list of valid/acceptable command line options and treat all others as unacceptable. "Sendmail look alike" may accept quite non standard options.

BTW "sendmail from sendmail.org" is no longer installed (by default) as **set root id**.

Comment: That means I need to know and parse all options of all versions of all sendmails I will encounter, so I'll need to keep tweaking my code. If I can be sure no options ever change the mode of operation except the `-b` options that saves a lot of trouble.

Comment: It means you should know *basic* set of options shared by sendmail and sendmail-look-alikes e.g. options used by a few widespread email clients.

Comment: Apparently, the text I linked to is an attempt at a common specification for sendmail, and it appears to have found some adoption: the sendmail manpage on my Ubuntu installation uses the same text. But it doesn't say anything about what additional nonstandard options may or may not do.